# phonegap build issue with simple navigator.notification.alert

Tags: alert, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm using phonegap build to compile my android apk, when I call a simple

```
navigator.notification.alert(
      'This is my message',     // mensaje (message)
      alertDismissed,         // función 'callback' (alertCallback)
      'Game Over',            // titulo (title)
      'Close'                // nombre del botón (buttonName)
      );
```

it doesn't work Here is my index.html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my index.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    app.showAlert();
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    alertDismissed: function()
    {
      console.log('called function');
    },
    showAlert: function()
    {

     navigator.notification.alert(
      'Eres el ganador!',     // mensaje (message)
      alertDismissed,         // función 'callback' (alertCallback)
      'Game Over',            // titulo (title)
      'Cerrar'                // nombre del botón (buttonName)
      );
    },
};
```

The app starts and shows "DEVICE IS READY" but the alert doesn't appear

Sorry for my english and thanks for help me

Answer (score 0):

Try including all your script tags in the `<head>` of your index.html. I have a feeling deviceready is not getting called because it is already "ready" by the time it tries to load phonegap.js.